# Threejs Fiber mesh interaction with react-postprocessing camera distortion shader

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I would like to mention that I just have started working with threejs and webgl.

The basic idea is that I have a 2d plane with several meshes that the user can interact with by both manipulating the camera angles as well as clicking on the meshes.

The entire scene has a radial camera distortion ([pincussion distortion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion_(optics))).

The problem is that the on click listeners of the meshes don't work as expected. Clicking in the scene only fires the event listeners of the meshes at their original (non-distorted) position in the scene.

Thx in advance, any help is appreciated.

For the shader application I used the lens distortion pass provided by [ycw](https://github.com/ycw/three-lens-distortion) and created a custom effect for [react-postprocessing](https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-postprocessing/effects/custom-effects).

```
export interface PincussionDistortionProps {
  distortion: Vector2;
  principalPoint: Vector2;
  focalLength: Vector2;
  skew: number;
}

const LensDistortionEffect = forwardRef<PincussionDistortionProps, any>(
  ({ distortion, principalPoint, focalLength, skew }, ref) => {
    const { camera, scene } = useThree();

    const effect = useMemo(() => {
      return new LensDistortionPass(scene, camera, {
        distortion,
        principalPoint,
        focalLength,
        skew,
      });
    }, [scene, camera, distortion, principalPoint, focalLength, skew]);

    return <primitive ref={ref} object={effect} />;
  }
);
```

*Fragment Shader*

```c
uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;
uniform vec2 uK0;
uniform vec2 uCc;
uniform vec2 uFc;
uniform float uAlpha_c;
varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {
    vec2 Xn = 2. * ( vUv.st - .5 ); // -1..1
    vec3 Xd = vec3(( 1. + uK0 * dot( Xn, Xn ) ) * Xn, 1.); // distorted
    mat3 KK = mat3(
    vec3(uFc.x, 0., 0.),
    vec3(uAlpha_c * uFc.x, uFc.y, 0.),
    vec3(uCc.x, uCc.y, 1.)
    );
    vec2 Xp = ( KK * Xd ).xy * .5 + .5; // projected; into 0..1
    if ( Xp.x >= 0. && Xp.x <= 1. && Xp.y >= 0. && Xp.y <= 1. ) {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D( tDiffuse, Xp );
    }
}
```

*Vertex Shader*

```c
varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {
    vUv = uv;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```